# Trouble initializing array in c

Tags: c

when I type the following code I get an "array initializer must be an initializer list or string literal" error. Can someone please explain how to properly initialize arrays with argv

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main (int argc, char* argv[]){

    char first[100] = argv[1];
    char second[100] = argv[2];

}
```

Comment: `argv[1]` is a pointer, not an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of arrays, you can use pointers:

```
char* first = argv[1];
char* second = argv[2];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this when assigning values to strings:

```
char first[100];
char second[100];

strcpy(first, argv[1]);
strcpy(second, argv[2]);
```

If you want to be able to receive input of almost any size, then it is recommended (as others have suggested) to use a pointer.

```
 char * first = argv[1];
 char * second = argv[2];
```

Check [this](https://computer.howstuffworks.com/c35.htm) resource for a tutorial on strings in C.

Comment: This blithely assumes that neither `argv[1]` nor `argv[2]` is longer than 99 characters (plus trailing null byte); it also assumes that both `argv[1]` and `argv[2]` are non-null.  It might be OK if you said as much.  (Yes, the question also assumes that they're both non-null pointers.  But answers are supposed to help fix problems with the code in the question — or at least point out issues that aren't fixed.)

Comment: If you read his question carefully he asks how to initialize *arrays* :). Also, it is quite possible that he knows what a reasonable limit is.